# Use of fgets in c

Tags: c

I need to write a program which converts a number from one base to another.
i need to get a user input in the form of: `<original base><new base><number in original base>`

I’m not allowed to use scanf and also im not allowed to assume the size of the line.
I have already tried using `fgets()` but I don’t know how to use it without limiting the size. I would love to get some ideas of what to do. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int BaseChanger()
{
    char input[12];
    printf("enter the original base, new base ,number");
    fgets(input, 12, stdin);
}
```

Comment: @Efrat.shp  Allocate dynamically an array of a fixed size. If after a call of fgets the arry does not contain the new line character realloc the array with a greater size and call fgets again using the position in the array where the previous string ends.

Comment: @xing `getline` is not a standard C function, what makes you think it is available and allowed in this assignment?

Comment: Suppose you have managed to read a line somehow. What would you do with it? Can you do the same exact thing with characters read one by one from the file?

Comment: Replace 12 with a bigger number. I use 4096 in such situations. If the first line in the file is longer than that, there are problems. If you limit yourself to 12 characters including one null, one newline, and 2 blanks, you haven’t got much space for numbers.

Comment: Are the numbers always non-negative?

Comment: Read 1 character at a time to form the numbers.  No buffer for a limited line length of user input required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet as a form of `getline`

```
int max= 100;
char* array;
array = malloc(max*sizeof(char));
if(array == NULL)
  exit(1);
int c,i=0;
while( ( c = getchar()) != EOF  &&  c != '\n' &&  i < max ) {
    array[ i++ ] = c ;
    if( i == max)
    {
       char * narray = realloc(array, max *= 2);
       if( narray == NULL ){
            free(array);
            exit(1);
       }
       array = narray;
    }
    ...
}
```

Once you do this, extract the numbers and then do the rest of the logic.

Comment: Hey, thanks. we didnt learn about pointers yet and allocating memory. is there a way in which you dont have to use that?

Comment: And dynamically allocate without using pointer? No..not posible